# Obtaining field from table using primary key

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, revisionable

Using Laravel and Revisionable Package for tracking changes.  In my view I'm populating my table:

```
@foreach($revisions as $revision)
      @if($revision->key == 'created_at' && !$revision->old_value)
      <tr>
        <td>{{ $revision->revisionable_type }}</td>
        <td>{{ $revision->revisionable_id }}</td>
        <td width="50">{{ $revision->userResponsible()->first_name }}</td>
        <td Width="50"></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>{{ $revision->newValue() }}</td>
        <td width="150">{{ $revision->created_at }}</td>
      </tr>  
      @else
      <tr>
        <td>{{ $revision->revisionable_type }}</td>
        <td>{{ $revision->revisionable_id }}</td>
        <td width="50">{{ $revision->userResponsible()->first_name }}</td>
        <td width="50">{{ $revision->fieldName() }}</td>
        <td>{{ $revision->oldValue() }}</td>
        <td>{{ $revision->newValue() }}</td>
        <td width="150">{{ $revision->updated_at }}</td>
      </tr>  
      @endif 
@endforeach
```

The second column {{ $revision->revisionable_id }} happens to be the primary key of the user record that was modified.  I would like to return the email address or first_name/last_name of that users record.   I'm fairly new at this and could use a push in the right direction!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the model that given revision relates to by accessing the **revisionable** relation of that revision. In your case, in order to display the email property of related model, you could do the following:

```
<td>{{ $revision->revisionable->email }}</td>
```

Comment: From the docs: "To accept an answer: Choose one answer that you believe is the best solution to your problem. To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. You may change which answer is accepted, or simply un-accept the answer, at any time."

Answer (score 0):

from the variable names `revisionable_type` & `revisionable_id` I assume you're using many to many Polymorphic relation. based on that 
you've to define a relation in the `Revision` Model with the `User` like so:

```
public function users()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany('App\User', 'taggable');
    }
```

so you can use all the revisions related to this user `$revision->users` this will return array
and if you're sure that you've only one record related to this object like your case as I think. you can use `$revision->users->first()->email` or username, etc..

[Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations)

Comment: Thanks for the fast response and the link to the docs for the additional info!  Very much appreciated!